# Kotlin build task slowing build

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, build, android-build

I have been check the build analyzer and notice there is one Kotlin build task that is over 30% of the build time.

The "Reason task run" is given as

```
Value of input property 'compilerOptions.moduleName' has changed for task ':app:compileWefiprobetaDebugKotlin' 
Value of input property 'moduleName' has changed for task ':app:compileWefiprobetaDebugKotlin' 
Value of input property 'ownModuleName' has changed for task ':app:compileWefiprobetaDebugKotlin'
```

(our app is WeFiProBeta)

Is there something I can do to fix this?